# Which Android Studio version will work well on a laptop with 2GB of RAM?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

currently I'm using the latest stable version of Android Studio (3.0.1), however I noticed that its build process in the designer is a little bit slower than Visual Studio 2017 which is also installed in my laptop.

My laptop's specs is:
-RAM: 2gb
-Processor: Intel Core 2 CPU T5500 @1.66ghz
-Storage: 74.4gb

What Android Studio version do you think will be the best for my laptop?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#Requirements

Comment: None. Rather change to a better machine than worry about version.

Comment: youll need the newer versions to support new versions of android. time to upgrade or purchase a new comp.

Answer (score 2):

you might ran in to problems with that laptop.

the text blow is the minimum requirement for android studio but don't go with the minimum.

I have a Lenovo Z500 with 6GB of ram and Core i7 cpu but whenever I open the android studio I want to pull my hair.

its to heavy, not well optimized, and very hard to work with minimum requirement.

but be my guest and try it by your self.

> Microsoft® Windows® 7/8/10 (32- or 64-bit)
>
> 3 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended; plus 1 GB for the Android
>   Emulator
>
> 2 GB of available disk space minimum,
>
> 4 GB Recommended (500 MB for IDE + 1.5 GB for Android SDK and emulator
>   system image)
>
> 1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution

Comment: ... and have an SSD drive! Also recommended: enable virtualization in your BIOS settings.

Comment: I'm currently using it, with the version I have. It's just that, it's build process in the designer is a little bit slower than Visual Studio 2017 which is also installed in my laptop.